# Using .where with a comparison operators in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get user products whos quantity is not zero. I tried getting the products this way but it give me all products that belong to that user regardless of quantity.

```
@user = User.find(params[:id]) 
@products = @user.products.where(:quantity != 0)
```

Comment: For new Rails versions use `where.not` (`@user.products.where.not(quantity: 0)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Record uses a little magic here and there to help with conditions, but it is still Ruby, and there are limits to it. The expression

```
:quantity != 0
```

always evaluates to `true`. So your command ends up as:

```
@products = @user.products.where( true )
```

and that explains your unwanted result.

To code the query that you want, one possible syntax should be

```
@products = @user.products.where( "quantity != ?", 0 )
```

using a different way of constructing a SQL where clause. The placeholder syntax (using `?` and a list of values) is not really necessary here, but you should use it instead of Ruby's variable interpolation (e.g. `"#{variable}"`) as a matter of course, to reduce vulnerability to SQL injection attacks.